# Ensure block exists in config file with puppet

Tags: puppet, radvd

After this existing block

```
prefix 2a03:2267:4e6f:7264:0000:0000:0000:0000/64
 {
 };
```

I want to add a new block, if it doesn't exist already:

```
prefix fdda:fee6:0187:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/64
 {
 };
```

in `/etc/radvd.conf` ( not at the end of the file)

and then `/etc/init.d/radvd restart`

How do I manage this with puppet?

Comment: You want augeas for the first and then a service resource that subscribe to the augeas resource for the second. I dislike augeas so i can't help you from a low level.

Answer (score 2):

Install

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-stdlib
```

Then create a script addblock.pp:

```
file_line { "ensure $line in /etc/radvd.conf":
    path  => '/etc/radvd.conf',
    line  => "prefix fdda:fee6:0187:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000/64\n{\n};",
}


exec { "restart":
  command => '/etc/init.d/radvd restart',
  provider => shell,
  require => File_line["ensure $line in /etc/radvd.conf"],
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should try the script yourself before? 

Comment: @rubo77 : please use [puppetlabs/stdlib](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib).
`File_line` is not a default resource you have to have `include ::stdlib` in your init.pp and download the `puppetlabs/stdlib` module in `/path/to/puppet/modules/` directory

Comment: @rubo77: is this file static?

Comment: th e config file is static,yes. but the puppet script will be called more often and it should only change only if the line is missing

Comment: we are updating our mesh gateway with puppet. that is installing the server and at the same time adding changes if there are some. so I need a solution to check if the line exists and only if not, add it

Comment: no, it works, but it always adds the block again and again

Comment: anyway, this script does add the block at the end, which is not what I asked, I need it added after the other block.